# Inputing multiple usernames from text file to run in python script

Tags: python

I have the following script that gets me the public data of a webpage of the username. I currently have it working for one username.

```
usernames = ['johnsmith']

r = requests.get('https://url/'+username)
html = r.text.encode("utf-8")
text = html[html.index("htmlclass = ")+21:]
text = (text[:text.index("};</script>")]+"}").replace('\\"', "")
dictionary = loads(text)
```

I would like to extract multiple usernames from a txt file (data.txt) and run it simultanerously. I am able to convert the text from the txt file into a list.

```
# Usernames extracted from text file:
base = [line.rstrip() for line in open('data.txt')]
```

Example text in txt file:

```
janedoe
johnnyb
marcusx
taylors
```

But I'm not sure how to adjust my script to accept multiple usernames. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put your current code in a function and run the function on each username in the `base` list using, say, a list comprehension:

```
def get_username_data(username):
    r = requests.get('https://url/'+username)
    html = r.text.encode("utf-8")
    text = html[html.index("htmlclass = ")+21:]
    text = (text[:text.index("};</script>")]+"}").replace('\\"', "")
    return loads(text)

result = [get_username_data(uname) for uname in base]
```